# Formgroup binding in select boxes with Angular

Tags: html, angular, formarray, formgroups

I have a nested JSON array which i have to iterate to HTML using formgroup or formarray. This response is to be iterated into dynamically created select boxes depending on the length of array.
The JSON response coming in is:

```
var result = [{
    id: 1,
    options: [
      { option: 'Ram', toBeSelected: false },
      { option: 'Ravi', toBeSelected: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    options: [
      { option: 'Pooja', toBeSelected: false },
      { option: 'Prakash', toBeSelected: false }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have to iterate this into HTML in such a way that if any of these options have `toBeSelected` as `true`, that option should be preselected in HTML and if not, placeholder text can be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `JSON` in question, you can make it like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this._FormBuilder.group({
      selections: this._FormBuilder.array([])
    });

    // the api call should be made here
    this.jsonResponse.map(item => {
        const opts = item.options.filter(o => {
            return o.toBeSelected
        });
        if (opts.length) {
            this.addSelections(opts[0].option);
        } else {
            this.addSelections();
        }
    });
}

get selections() {
    return this.form.get('selections') as FormArray
}

addSelections(value?: string) {
    this.selections.push(
        this._FormBuilder.control((value ? value : ''))
    );
}
```

Live view [here](https://dynamic-form-binding-kx7nqf.stackblitz.io/).

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-form-binding-kx7nqf

Comment: you have done this for radio buttons and not dropdown select boxes with hardcoded 2 options. This data would also come dynamically. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Thanks man! this works as required. Just one update i wanted even if user has not selected anything the form is valid.

Comment: Then, you need to set the validation in the form.

Comment: Ya i think that would be good. Like if the   <option value="">Select option</option> is the selected one then form should be invalid

Comment: Oh! Just forgot the validators in there. You saved my day!

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow. So dont have rights to upvote but i have selected your answer

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this?

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results">
  <p>ID - {{ result.id }}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let option of result.options">
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      [checked]="option.toBeSelected">
      {{ option.option }}
  </div>
</div>
```

This isn't an example of FormGroup though but should help you understand how it can be done.

[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-example-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: But i need to integrate it with formarray or formgroup for validations and this doesnot cover the part if none of the options are selected, placeholder shows

Comment: So you're looking for a Reactive form in that case? Or a template Driven Form? I think you should be going for a Reactive Form.

Comment: Yes reactive form

Comment: Okay. I'm working on it. I'll update my answer soon.